# Fstream in out code::blocks error

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
std::fstream out;

out.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream out);
if(out.is_open()){
```

While compiling `Code::Blocks`, I get the following error:

> expected primary-expression before "out"

Any ideas as to what could be causing this error?

---

I'm trying to rewrite file for 5 times

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc<2){
        printf("Error! Usage: wrap.exe filename\n");
        return -1;
    }
    std::fstream out;

    out.open(argv[1], std::fstream::in | std::fstream out);
    if(out.is_open()){

    out.seekp(0,out.beg);
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        while(!out.eof()){
        out<<i;
                        }
    }
    }
else {
    printf("Error! Problem with opening file to wrap!\n");
    return -1;
}
out.close();
printf("File wrapped successfully!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Compiling Code::Blocks", or "compiling *with* Code::Blocks"?  Code::Blocks is not in any case a compiler, it is an IDE.

Comment: This isn't the problem, but you should use the constructor to open the file. `std::fstream out(argue[1]);` will do what you need. No need for the separate call to `open`, and no need for the mode arguments, since they're the default values (same thing in calling `open`: `out.open(argv[1]);` is sufficient).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote a space instead of `::` between `std::fstream` and `out` in the `open` line.